# servers with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was doing the following on the terminal:

```
script/server
```

it says the server host:3000 was being used,

when I typed it into web browser, the page loads but when I click on my environment the info doesn't show up. I get an error message

if I change the server by typing in

```
script/server -p 3001
```

for example, it works,

so my question is: how does one disconnect or erase the previous "3000" port so that I can use 3000 instead of 3001?

Is there a command line for this in the terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: the error: server already in use (referring to host:3000)

Answer (score 4):

Port 3000 is being used by something else, so you need to stop whatever process that is first. Probably that is another `script/server` instance, so kill it. If it isn't, well, you can try `sudo lsof -i :3000` to try and figure it out... but it might be easier to just reboot your box and try again :)

Comment: reboot as in restarting the computer?

Comment: yeah, but you really shouldn't have to reboot your box -- as thenduks said, there is another ./script/server running somewhere… try his command, or maybe `ps aux |grep server` or `ps aux | grep ruby`… if you find it in the list, kill it with `kill <pidnumber>` -- good luck!